# How to insert bean:message into string?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'd like to do the following

```
<div id="Grants the " + <bean:message key="label.foo/>/>
```

How can this be done? Basically, it's concatenating a bean:message to a string.

Comment: JSP procudes HTML. It doesn't run in sync with HTML or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed Struts (and other JSP tag library) tags inside regular HTML tags:

```
<div id="Grants the <bean:message key="label.foo"/>"/>
```

If the message resource with the key `label.foo` had the text "Foo" mapped to it, then the result would be:

```
<div id="Grants the Foo"/>
```

Though it's worth noting that wouldn't be a valid value for the `id` attribute.